# spark join two dataframes and convert result dataframe to desired json format

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given two DataFramemes.

DF1 is :

```
|emp_id|emp_site             |emp_name  

|1     |Washigton            | [Will, Smith] 
|2     |null                 | null
|3     |New York             | [Norman, Smith]
|4     |Iowa                 | [Ian, Smith]
```

DF2 is :

```
|emp_id|emp_site             |emp_name  

|1     |Washigton            | [Watson, Smith] 
|2     |Wisconsin            | [Sam, Robinson]
|3     |New York             | null
|4     |Illinois             | [Ican, Robinson]
|5     |Pennsylvania         | [Patrick, Robinson]
```

Expected is a DF3 which is a join of DF1 and DF2 on the empty_id column(outer join such that all DF2 records are available). DF3 to have all the columns(except for emp_id) represented in the form of 'from', 'to' and 'change' ONLY IF the respective column values from DF1 and DF2 differ(NOTE: if column values from DF1 and DF2 are equal then should be null ).

note: While 'from' and 'to' are self explanatory containing values from DF1 and DF2, 'change' indicates 'insert' if the 'from' value is null. otherwise indicates 'update'

```
|emp_id|emp_site                         |emp_name

|1     |null                             |[from -> [Will, Smith], to -> [Watson, Smith], change->update]
|2     |[to->Wisconsin, change->insert]  |[to -> [Sam, Robinson], change->update]
|3     |null                             |[from -> [Norman, Smith], change->update]
|4     |[from ->Iowa, to -> Illinois, change->insert]    |[from ->[Ian, Smith], to -> [Ican, Robinson], change-> insert]
|5     |[to -> Pennsylvania, change->insert]         | [to -> [Patrick, Robinson], change->insert]
```

Had no success trying to achieve this desired DF3 using Map (esp. because the column types are not always Strings i.e., 'from' and 'to' can hold struct types depending on column types in df1 and df2). reason for trying with map data structure to build 'from', 'to' and 'change' in DF3 is because eventually this DF3 needs to be translated to a json.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen similar query in the past.

Comment: still need help on this as the suggestions have limitations with using maps.

Comment: can you please check my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

### 1. Load the input

```
  val data =
      """
        |emp_id|emp_site             |emp_name
        |1     |Washigton            | Will
        |2     |null                 | null
        |3     |New York             | Norman
        |4     |Iowa                 | Ian
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +------+---------+--------+
      * |emp_id|emp_site |emp_name|
      * +------+---------+--------+
      * |1     |Washigton|Will    |
      * |2     |null     |null    |
      * |3     |New York |Norman  |
      * |4     |Iowa     |Ian     |
      * +------+---------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- emp_id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- emp_site: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- emp_name: string (nullable = true)
      */


    val data1 =
      """
        |emp_id|emp_site             |emp_name
        |1     |Washigton            | Watson
        |2     |Wisconsin            | Sam
        |3     |New York             | null
        |4     |Illinois             | Ican
        |5     |Pennsylvania         | Patrick
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS1 = data1.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df2 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    /**
      * +------+------------+--------+
      * |emp_id|emp_site    |emp_name|
      * +------+------------+--------+
      * |1     |Washigton   |Watson  |
      * |2     |Wisconsin   |Sam     |
      * |3     |New York    |null    |
      * |4     |Illinois    |Ican    |
      * |5     |Pennsylvania|Patrick |
      * +------+------------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- emp_id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- emp_site: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- emp_name: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### 2. Process to required format

```scala
 val joiningKey = "emp_id"
    val cols =
      df1.columns.filterNot(_.equals(joiningKey)).zip(df2.columns.filterNot(_.equals(joiningKey)))
        .map { c  =>
            val (df1Col, df2Col) = df1.col(c._1) -> df2.col(c._2)
            when(df1Col.isNull && df2Col.isNotNull,
              array(map(lit("to"), df2Col), map(lit("change"), lit("insert"))))
            .when(df1Col.isNotNull && df2Col.isNull,
              array(map(lit("from"), df1Col), map(lit("change"), lit("delete"))))
              .when(df1Col.isNotNull && df2Col.isNotNull && df1Col === df2Col,
                lit(null))
              .when(df1Col.isNull && df2Col.isNull,
                lit(null))
              .otherwise(array(map(lit("from"), df1Col), map(lit("to"), df2Col), map(lit("change"), lit("update"))))
            .as(c._1)

          }

    df1.join(df2, Seq(joiningKey), "outer")
      .select(cols ++ Seq(col(colName = joiningKey)): _*)
      .orderBy(joiningKey)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+
      * |emp_site                                              |emp_name                                            |emp_id|
      * +------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+
      * |null                                                  |[[from -> Will], [to -> Watson], [change -> update]]|1     |
      * |[[to -> Wisconsin], [change -> insert]]               |[[to -> Sam], [change -> insert]]                   |2     |
      * |null                                                  |[[from -> Norman], [change -> delete]]              |3     |
      * |[[from -> Iowa], [to -> Illinois], [change -> update]]|[[from -> Ian], [to -> Ican], [change -> update]]   |4     |
      * |[[to -> Pennsylvania], [change -> insert]]            |[[to -> Patrick], [change -> insert]]               |5     |
      * +------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+
      */
```

### 3. Use Struct if the datatype of input column is other than string (based on comments)

```scala
  // in case column is not of type string
    val getExpr = (fromExpr: String, toExpr: String, changeExpr: String) =>
      s"named_struct('from', $fromExpr, 'to', $toExpr, 'change', '$changeExpr')"
    val cols1 =
      df1.columns.filterNot(_.equals(joiningKey)).zip(df2.columns.filterNot(_.equals(joiningKey)))
        .map { c =>
          val (c1, c2) = s"df1.${c._1}" -> s"df2.${c._2}"
          when(expr(s"$c1 is null and $c2 is not null"), expr(getExpr("null", c2, "insert")))
            .when(expr(s"$c1 is not null and $c2 is null"), expr(getExpr(c1, "null", "delete")))
            .when(expr(s"$c1 is not null and $c2 is not null and $c1=$c2"), expr(getExpr("null", "null", "null")))
            .when(expr(s"$c1 is null and $c2 is null"), expr(getExpr("null", "null", "null")))
            .otherwise(expr(getExpr(c1, c2, "update")))
            .as(c._1)
        }

    val processedDF = df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"), Seq(joiningKey), "outer")
      .select(cols1 ++ Seq(col(colName = joiningKey)): _*)
      .orderBy(joiningKey)
    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------------------------+----------------------+------+
      * |emp_site                |emp_name              |emp_id|
      * +------------------------+----------------------+------+
      * |[,, null]               |[Will, Watson, update]|1     |
      * |[, Wisconsin, insert]   |[, Sam, insert]       |2     |
      * |[,, null]               |[Norman,, delete]     |3     |
      * |[Iowa, Illinois, update]|[Ian, Ican, update]   |4     |
      * |[, Pennsylvania, insert]|[, Patrick, insert]   |5     |
      * +------------------------+----------------------+------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- emp_site: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- to: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- change: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- emp_name: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- to: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- change: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- emp_id: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

> Please note if the `from` and `to` are not present, I'm using change as `null`, you can change that to something  else like `no-op`

Comment: Appreciate it. However this solution with the maps fails when the columns are not of type string. which is the same callout I had:
Had no success trying to achieve this desired DF3 using Map (esp. because the column types are not always Strings i.e., 'from' and 'to' can hold struct types depending on column types in df1 and df2). reason for trying with map data structure to build 'from', 'to' and 'change' in DF3 is because eventually this DF3 needs to be translated to a json.

Comment: Is there a way we can extend this solution to columns of all types(some columns are custom structs for instance).

Comment: It should work for all type of cols..can you tell me the example where it won't?

Comment: consider If the emp_name is of type array(struct("firstname", "last name"))  
Example data record for emp_name from DF1 could be: [[Will, Hart], [Sam, Smith]] and lets say in DF2 its changed to [[Will, Smith], [Sam, Burns]]   then in the DF3 we want to see [[Will, Hart], [Sam, Smith]] ->  [[Will, Smith], [Sam, Burns]]

Comment: since each column might have its own type, I believe we need to build a struct/map which infers the type of its 'from' and 'to' from corresponding column types in data frames(df1 and df2), and then appends 'change' which is always of type string.

Comment: Can you please take one example and try it. If it fails, edit the description with the new dataset and its expected output. I still believe it will work

Comment: Sure. updated the dataset with Array(Struct) type for emp_name. I am seeing type mismatch error with this dataset : cannot resolve 'array(map('to', `emp_name`), map('change', 'insert'))' due to data type mismatch:

Comment: see my edited answer, specifically bullet #3. Feel free to upvote + accept if it helps